# Group scale-based visibility QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, scale, visibility

Is it possible to set scale-based visibility for groups or sub-groups of layers in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no option to set scale-based visibility for a `group` / `subgroup`.

As a workaround, you can select (highlight) the layers in the group (holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, if you are on Windows), then `right-click` to call a context menu `"Set layer-Scale visibility"`.

[image]

This setting is applied to all the layers you have highlighted.